# Context free/Non Context free Language

Tags: automata

Let L = { uv composed of {0,1}  |  |u| = |v| and u = v }

Do we agree that this language is not a Context Free Language ?

If not, why ? Can you give me a pushdown automata that recognizes it or the grammar that describes it ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: This is a standard example mentioned in many automata theory textbooks as an example of a language that is not context-free.  I'd suggest you start by studying our reference material on standard methods to prove that a language is not context-free, then try applying the standard methods (pumping lemma, etc.) to this language.  If you get stuck, then perhaps you can edit your question to show what you've tried so far, what progress you've made, and articulate a specific question about what has you confused.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Problem solved